# Models for two theories, first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

The exercise: language $L$ contains one-argument function $f$, and $=$ relation symbol. given that:
$M : {W^M=\mathbb Q, f^M(a) = a+1}$ and $N : {W^N=\mathbb Z, f^N(a) = a+1}$ are $L$-structures. Is there a sentence $\alpha$ in $L$ such that $M \models \alpha $ and $N \not\models \alpha$.

I've shown that $M,N$ are models for first-order-logic theory $\Sigma$ which defines $f$ one-to-one and onto function **without cycles**. $\Sigma$ has no finite models and it is $\kappa > \aleph _0 $ categorial, therefore $\Sigma$ is complete, so every two models for $\Sigma$ satisfies the same sentences (by definition of complete theory), Therefore there is no such $\alpha$ as represented in the question.

Yet my problem is, maybe $M$ and $N$ are models for $\Sigma_2$ which  is not necessarily complete. Generally speaking, if 2 models are simultaneously models for complete theory and for non-complete theory (In case this scenario is possible) do my arguments stand?

Comment: Your argument is correct, and it never assumed that $M$ and $N$ are not also models of some other, incomplete theory.  In fact, they are models of the incomplete theory with the same language and no axioms.  But so what?

Answer (score 1):

For the second part observe that the theory saying "$f$ is a one to one function" is not complete and both $N$ and $M$ are models of this theory. Yet your first argument is independent of this.

In general a structure can be a model of a complete theory as well as a non complete theory. Another example, $\mathbb C$ is a model of ACF, the theory of algebraically closed fields. ACF is not complete (observe that it has models of characteristic $0$ as well as positive characteristic). But $\mathbb C$ is also a model of ACF$_0$, the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$, which is a complete theory.